# Invalid Form Key in admin panel

Tags: php, magento

I'm working with magento 1.6.2, I migrated server and in administration zone can't edit/create products and categories, always get the same message: Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.
I check the code and in the code i have the form key:

```
var FORM_KEY = 'GDhFgYdZ6r5NtPtL';
"params":{"form_key":"GDhFgYdZ6r5NtPtL"}
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="GDhFgYdZ6r5NtPtL" />
```

I had trouble with the cookies above  but I solved it configuring the path and domain cookie, if it will help.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing your issue -- but you certainly want to be running a more recent version of Magento.  Extensions stop thinking about earlier versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the server configuration, i've change the max_input_vars parameter and the message dissapeared. I saw the solution in http://www.webcroppers.com/magento-invalid-form-key-please-refresh-the-page/